# MSDeploy Unauthorized Error

Tags: command-line, msdeploy, webdeploy, unauthorized

I am calling msdeploy using the command line to deploy a web deploy package (zip) to the same machine that I am running the command from.

Here is the command line:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="<pathToZip>" -dest:auto,computerName="<hostName>",includeAcls="False",authType=Basic,userName="<myUserName>",password="<myPassword>" -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"<pathToSetParametersXml>" -allowUntrusted -preSync:runCommand="<pathToPreDeployCmd",waitattempts=10,waitinterval=30000 -postSync:runCommand="<pathToPostDeployCmd>",waitattempts=5,waitinterval=30000
```

I've tried this with the msdeploy.axd url, with msdeploy.axd?site url, and with just the host name of the computer.  When I run this command on the local machine where it is deploying to, the command fails with an unauthorized exception despite the user being an admin.  I ran the same command on a remote computer and it worked when I just used the host name as the ComputerName.

For some reason the same command works remotely but not locally.  I copied and pasted the exact command.  I've used both the computer host name as well as localhost locally with no luck.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the destination `computername` to "localhost".